# need a help to fetch account name from account records by passing phone

Tags: apex

need a help to fetch account name from account records by passing phone.i've written code in apex, getting error at line no 4, can anyone help me what mistake i did make in the code?

```
public class AccountNamefromPhone {
    public set<string> fetchACCName(string p){
        set<string> s1=new set<string>();
        List<Account>acc=[select id,Name from Account where Phone ];
        for(Account a:acc)
        {
            string s=a.name;
            s1.add(s);

        }
        system.debug('the account name is' +s1);
        return s1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SOQL is incomplete.

Replace the SOQL line with following:

```
List<Account>acc=[select id,Name from Account where Phone =:p ];
```

Assuming parameter `p` is the Phone number.

Learn more with trailhead module- [Write SOQL Queries](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql)